# Where and how is Geil used?

Tags: slang, offensive-language

The [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) writes:

> GEIL (Guy-el)  The best colloquial
>   word ever established by the German
>   language. It has slowly assimilated
>   itself into English speaking culture,
>   particularly the Southeast of America.
>   These cities such as: Charleston,
>   Charlotte, Atlanta, and Chattanooga
>   the word 'GEIL' is used frequently and
>   interchangeably between the people
>   whom reside there.
>
> Simple in Context:
>
> Im so Geil! (Fucked up)  Wanna get
>   Geil? (Wanna get wasted/fucked
>   up/nutty/lit..etc)  She's fucking
>   Geil! (She is hot and DTF) Brad, im so
>   fucking GEIL!
>
> Hey Chad, you down to get GEIL
>   tonight?
>
> Hey is that Wendy Brown over there by
>   the bartop? Yea, it is chad. Damn,
>   she's GEIL.she's GEIL.
>
> she's GEIL.

**My questions:**

- Is this true and are there other areas where this word is known and used?
- Is there only the sexual connotation or could it also be used like "that's cool" (because the meaning in German has changed that way over the years)
- How taboo is it? mild or strong (I guess peergroup dependent...)?

Comment: I have never known an English speaker to use *geil*, or even be aware of its existence, unless that person studied the German language.  Perhaps someone from the Southeast US will say otherwise, but I have serious doubts.

Comment: I've never heard this used as slang in English.  I'm also not from the Southeast, so I can't reliably rule out it's use there, but if you go to http://search.twitter.com/ and search, there don't seem to be any English tweets using the word.  You'd think if it were popular, it would at least show up there.

Comment: Here's a continental European chiming in. *Geil* is incredibly common (and completely harmless) in German, but I have never, ever seen or heard it in an English context. (Also, as far as German is concerned, it wasn't ever taboo to begin with. I know a few older Germans who do tend to avoid it, but even they would never insist on its being obscene. The original meaning is "horny", and the most popular current one, as you say, is "cool".)

Comment: Urban Dictionary has a lot of examples of rare but real slang terms. It also has a lot of bogus hoax terms. Based on the answers and comments here, it looks like *geil* is a hoax term, but stranger things have turned out to not be hoaxes, so...

Comment: I have never heard it from an English speaking person, but then again, I've never been to above mentioned towns. If it is used in any way similar to German, then it can be a synonym of either cool, fun, sexually attractive, or sexually aroused, depending on the context. Some of those uses listed by you would not be correct if translated literally to German, except the last two. The first two meanings are usually attributed to inanimate things or activities, whereas the sexual meanings to persons. Also, it is not used as a synonym of wasted. But hey, loanwords are known to change meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't heard geil spoken by English or American speakers at all. I know what it means from some German rap songs I listened to, but it definitely is not common in English. You can un-asterikize the title =P.

Funny though, how if you [google geil](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=geil), the links are pretty harmless, except for the ads, which are all about "Nude XXX Pictures - Free!"

Comment: I studied German in high school (lo these many years, or is that decades, ago), and never heard of the word.

Comment: yeah they wouldn't teach you how to say 'horny' in class necessarily =P. gotta hit up the music. Rammstein is fun. B-Tight is like hardcore rap, thats where i heard it, in a song called "Neger bums mich."